# Power supply unit for a led driver

Tags: power-supply, led

can anyone suggest an efficient transformer-less power supply unit for a led driver. Since most common topologies for transformer-less power supply units are capacitor based methods which are associated with low efficiency, i want to find an efficient design for a transformer-less power supply unit..

Comment: How much power are you talking about?

Comment: I cannot stress enough, the critical importance of writing down all input output specs for; V, I , Z load before doing any design!!   and issues like flicker and specs for Ipk/Iavg max tolerance which is very low in LEDs. Then you will see the reason why your request fails!!

Comment: How about a battery?

Comment: "associated with low efficiency" in what sense? The capacitive voltage drop produces very little heat (power loss) due to the out of phase current (much less than if a resistor had been used). Granted they are limited to fairly small currents but that is a totally different issue to efficiency.

Comment: It is completely unclear what the requirements are in terms of input and output voltage, etc, so it is not possible to give a sensible answer or rate the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

- When you have a transformer in mind, I assume you use a AC Supply?
- How much power do you estimate?

If you don't use much power you could use a buck converter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6s3Fz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

its a high performance buck type.
when the input Voltage is below 38V, The zener is off and the C1 Charges to that Voltage. after rising over 38V, D1 Conducts, Q1 is turned on and M1 Mosfet is turned off. so we have a Constant 38 V in output.
The Author Claims up to 1A Output Current with a Switching 5V Regulator.
design of  Paul Goossens. Elektor Magazine.

Comment: Its also a highly lethal design in terms of galvanic isolation.

Comment: unfortunately yes. its best used in internal applications with no user interaction. @JImDearden

Answer (score 0):

I cannot stress enough, the critical importance of writing down all input output specs for; V, I , Z load before doing any design!! and issues like flicker and AC voltage tolerance specs . At nominal Voltage of 230VAC 50Hz it is only 50% efficient because I increased the low voltage cap to reduce I ripple from 100% to 25%pp.

Actually the most Efficient AC-DC is the SMPS regulator.  This is just an example, not the most efficient.

Of course **touching live off-grid voltages is unsafe** and all parts must be rated for Line transients.
[image]